# sound play on imagebutton click

Tags: android, imagebutton

i want to play sound here when click on image button. i tried to play sound but it crashes app on launch this is my code.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ImageButton imageButton;
    Animation performAnimation1;
    ImageView androidImageView;
    MediaPlayer mp;
    Button touch;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        addListenerOnButton();
        performAnimation1 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.layout.animation1);
        performAnimation1.setRepeatCount(4);
        androidImageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.androidImageView);
        androidImageView.startAnimation(performAnimation1);

        mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.click);
        touch = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        touch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                mp.start();
            }
        });
        }

    public void addListenerOnButton() {
        imageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        imageButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Numbers.class);
                    startActivity(intent); 
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Is it crashes due to i am using onClickListener twise in the code??

Comment: @vishesh chandra 01-17 03:33:24.841: E/AndroidRuntime(1798):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
01-17 03:33:24.841: E/AndroidRuntime(1798):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
01-17 03:33:24.841: E/AndroidRuntime(1798):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)

Comment: @SuRajPrince Can you edit your question and post your complete Logcat???

Comment: @visheshchandra this is logcat (http://brightcm.com/log.txt)

Comment: @visheshchandra sound is playing but it is not going to my next activity as it goes before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem:** I checked your logcat.

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageButton cannot be cast to android.widget.Button 
at com.android.learning_numbers.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:33)
```

Actually you are downcasting the ImageButton to Button, which is not possible.

```
touch = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.button1);
```

**Solution:**
Instead doing this please downcast it to ImageButton.

```
touch = (ImageButton)this.findViewById(R.id.button1);
```

**This is your code with correct downcasting.**

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
ImageButton imageButton;
Animation performAnimation1;
ImageView androidImageView;
MediaPlayer mp;
ImageButton touch;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    addListenerOnButton();
    performAnimation1 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.layout.animation1);
    performAnimation1.setRepeatCount(4);
    androidImageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.androidImageView);
    androidImageView.startAnimation(performAnimation1);

    mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.click);
    touch = (ImageButton)this.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    touch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            mp.start();
        }
    });
    }

public void addListenerOnButton() {
    imageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    imageButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Numbers.class);
                startActivity(intent); 
        }
    });
}

}
```

Check it and let me know if still you have any problem...!!!

Comment: sound is playing but it is not going to my next activity as it goes befor

Answer (score 1):

you need to set `R.anim` not `R.layout`

```
 performAnimation1 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.animation1);
```